# Bad render mobile menu only Iphone - diffrent height?

Tags: css, responsive

I have problem with my website.
I did responsive website with mobile menu and it's looking very good on Developere Mode with responsive and android phone but on iphone it look terrible..
Here on dev tools/android:
[image]

Here on iphone:

[image]

Code:
HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header-wrapper">
        <div class="header-logo" id="headerLogo">
            <img src="assets/images/logo_right.svg" alt="Logo company" height="70px">
        </div>
        <div class="header-logo header-logo--mobile">
            <img class="logo-mobile" src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo company" height="70px">
        </div>
        <div class="header-contact-container">
            <div class="header-contact__item">
                <div class="header-contact__icon">
                    <i class="gg-phone"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="site-nav" id="nav__main">
        <ul class="site-nav__list">
            <li class="site-nav__item site-nav__item--is-hidden">
                <a class="site-nav__anchor" href="#" id="mobile_nav">MENU</a>
            </li>
            <li class="site-nav__item">
                <a class="site-nav__anchor" href="javascript: scrollSmoothTo('mainWrapper')"
                   id="homeNavButton">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="site-nav__item">
                <a class="site-nav__anchor" href="javascript: scrollSmoothTo('aboutUs')"
                   id="aboutNavButton">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="site-nav__item">
                <a class="site-nav__anchor" href="javascript: scrollSmoothTo('services')" id="servicesNavButton">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="site-nav__item">
                <a class="site-nav__anchor" href="javascript: scrollSmoothTo('contact')" id="contactNavButton">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

CSS DEFAULT

```
.header {
    display: block;
}

.header-wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 65%;
    padding: 30px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-logo {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-logo--mobile {
    display: none;
}

.header-contact-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.header-contact__item {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.header-contact__title {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}

.header-contact__data {
    text-align: center;
}

.header-contact__icon {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    height: 100%;
}

.site-nav {
    height: 50px;
    background: rgb(250, 255, 253);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.68);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.68);
    z-index: 999;
}

.site-nav__list {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}

.site-nav__item--is-hidden {
    display: none;
}

.site-nav__item {
    width: 180px;
    height: 80%;
}

.site-nav__anchor {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: rgb(6, 67, 62);
    font-family: 'Sora', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none!important;
}

.site-nav__anchor:hover {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    color: #ffcc00;
}

.header-nav--sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

CSS MOBILE

```
    .header-wrapper {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .header-logo {
        display: none;
    }

    .header-logo--mobile {
        display: block;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .logo-mobile {
    }

    .header-contact-container {
        display: block;
    }

    .header-contact__item {
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: auto;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .header-contact__title {
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }

    .header-contact__data {
        display: block;
        /*-webkit-box-ordinal-group:3;*/
        /*-ms-flex-order:2;*/
        /*order:2;*/
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    .site-nav {
        height: auto!important;
    }

    .site-nav__list {
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: auto!important;
        /*height: auto;*/
    }

    .site-nav__item--is-hidden {
        display: block!important;
        background: #FFCC00;
        max-height: 100%!important;
    }

    .site-nav__item {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%!important;
    }

    .site-nav__anchor {
        padding: 15px 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    }

    .site-nav__anchor:nth-child(1):hover {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        color:inherit!important;
    }
```

JS

```
const mobileButtonMenu = document.getElementById("mobile_nav")
mobileButtonMenu.addEventListener("click", setMobileMenu);

function setMobileMenu() {
    const menu = document.querySelectorAll(".site-nav__item")
    if (menu[1].style.display === "block") {
        menu[1].style.display = "none";
        menu[2].style.display = "none";
        menu[3].style.display = "none";
        menu[4].style.display = "none";
    } else {
        menu[1].style.display = "block";
        menu[2].style.display = "block";
        menu[3].style.display = "block";
        menu[4].style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

I dont know what I have to do. I think that problem may be with height:auto, because other elements with flex was be good render.

Comment: Hard to say, but I would try to connect the iPhone to a Mac and then open up Safari to debug. You can find it your iPhone under the Developer submenu in the menu (but you need to make it visible somewhere in the settings of Safari). I guess it's the `-webkit-box` that messes everything up. Try change it to `-webkit-flex`.

Comment: I change but it's same . I have only iPhone so I can't do debugging.

Comment: I would try debugging through https://www.browserstack.com/live/features or some other site with a similar emulator service. You need to pay for Browser Stack, but you're working for a company, it's worth every penny. Can't give more advice then removing as much CSS as possible and just start from the ground up to see what works. Safari can be really cranky - it's the new Internet Explorer. Good luck!

Comment: I fixed. I set height on some value because with auto doesn't work